# Template copy constructor

Tags: c++

I need to create a copy constructor for my class MyVector.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class MyVector{
    private:
        T *v;
        int size;
        int max;

    public:
        MyVector();
        MyVector(const MyVector &l);
        MyVector& operator=(const MyVector &lhs);
        T &operator[](unsigned int i);
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}

template<class T>
MyVector& MyVector<T>::operator = (const MyVector &lhs){
    if (this == &lhs) return *this;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        delete v[i];
    }

    delete [] v;

    max = lhs.max;
    size = lhs.size;
    v = new T[max];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        v[i] = new T(*(lhs.v[i]));
    }

    return *this;
}
```

im getting the error: `expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before âmyVectorâ`

Not sure where the problem is, I am fairly new to c++.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the problem:

```
template<class T>
MyVector& MyVector<T>::operator = (const MyVector &lhs){
  /* ... */
}
```

The return type, `MyVector&` should be `MyVector<T>&` because you're outside of the class scope, so you need to provide the template parameter there, like this:

```
template<class T>
MyVector<T>& MyVector<T>::operator = (const MyVector &lhs){
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It hit me when I was reading your answer that that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the return for the function implementation, write `MyVector<T>`.

```
template<class T>
MyVector<T>& MyVector<T>::operator = (const MyVector &lhs)
{
```

Note that you're implementing an assignment operator, not a copy constructor.

A nice alternative is to use C++11 syntax where the return type *follows* the function head:

```
template<class T>
auto MyVector<T>::operator = (const MyVector &lhs)
    -> MyVector&
{
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyVector(const MyVector &l);
```

should be:

```
MyVector(const MyVector<T> &l);
```

and similarly everywhere else you use `MyVector` as a type, since the type is not complete without the template arguments.

Comment: Within a template class scope, the use of the name is implicitly the complete type. So within `MyVector<T>`'s scope, the use of the name `MyVector` is actually `MyVector<T>`.